# Does clojure have the C# equivalent of yield?

Tags: clojure

I was reading the ebook [Functional Programming Patterns in Scala & Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/mbfpp/functional-programming-patterns-in-scala-and-clojure) and found a code sample that led to this question.

This piece of code is meant to compare two Person objects. The comparision algo is - First compare their FNames, if equal then compare their LName, if equal then compare their MNames.

Clojure code as given in the book (more or less)

```
(def person1 {:fname "John" :mname "Q" :lname "Doe"})
(def person2 {:fname "Jane" :mname "P" :lname "Doe"})

(defn fname-compare [p1 p2] 
  (do 
    (println "Comparing fname")
    (compare (:fname p1) (:fname p2))))

(defn lname-compare [p1 p2] 
  (do 
    (println "Comparing lname")
    (compare (:lname p1) (:lname p2))))

(defn mname-compare [p1 p2] 
  (do 
    (println "Comparing mname")
    (compare (:mname p1) (:mname p2))))

(defn make-composed-comparison [& comparisons] 
  (fn [p1 p2]
    (let [results (for [comparison comparisons] (comparison p1 p2)) 
          first-non-zero-result 
            (some (fn [result] (if (not (= 0 result)) result nil)) results)] 
      (if (nil? first-non-zero-result)
        0
        first-non-zero-result))))

(def people-comparision-1 
  (make-composed-comparison fname-compare lname-compare mname-compare))

(people-comparision-1 person1 person2)

;Output
;Comparing fname
;Comparing lname
;Comparing mname
;14
```

Thing is, as per this sample it will do all three comparisons even if the first one returned non zero. In this case its not an issue. However if I had written idiomatic C# code, then that code would have done only one comparison and exited. Sample C# code

```
public class Person {
  public string FName {get; set;}
  public string LName {get; set;}
  public string MName {get; set;}
}

var comparators = 
  new List<Func<Person, Person, int>> {
    (p1, p1) => {
      Console.WriteLine("Comparing FName");
      return string.Compare(p1.FName, p2.FName);
    },
    (p1, p1) => {
      Console.WriteLine("Comparing LName");
      return string.Compare(p1.LName, p2.LName);
    },
    (p1, p1) => {
      Console.WriteLine("Comparing MName");
      return string.Compare(p1.MName, p2.MName);
    }
  };

var p1 = new Person {FName = "John", MName = "Q", LName = "Doe"};
var p2 = new Person {FName = "Jane", MName = "P", LName = "Doe"};

var result = 
  comparators
    .Select(x => x(p1, p2))
    .Where(x => x != 0)
    .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(result);

// Output
// Comparing FName
// 1
```

A naive translation of the above code into clojure gives me

```
(defn compose-comparators [& comparators]
  (fn [x y]
    (let [result 
          (->> comparators
              (map #(% x y))
              (filter #(not (zero? %)))
              first)]
      (if (nil? result)
        0
        result))))

(def people-comparision-2 
  (compose-comparators fname-compare lname-compare mname-compare))

(people-comparision-2 person1 person2)

;Output
;Comparing fname
;Comparing lname
;Comparing mname
;14
```

And that is not what I expected. I read somewhere that clojure processes 32 elements of a sequence at a time for performance reasons or something. What is the idiomatic Clojure way to get the output/behaviour similar to the C# code?

The following is my attempt. However it doesn't feel "clojurey".

```
(defn compose-comparators-2 [& comparators]
  (fn [x y] 
    (loop [comparators comparators
          result 0]
      (if (not (zero? result))
        result
        (let [comparator (first comparators)]
          (if (nil? comparator)
          0
          (recur (rest comparators) (comparator x y))))))))

(def people-comparision-3 
  (compose-comparators-2 fname-compare lname-compare mname-compare))

(people-comparision-3 person1 person2)

;Output
;Comparing fname
;14
```

**Edit** :

Based on answers to this question as well as the [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26045974/30007), I think if I need early exit, I should be explicit about it. One way would be to convert the collection to a lazy one. The other option is to use `reduced` to exit early from the reduce loop.

With the knowledge I currently have, I am more inclined to opt for the explicit lazy collection route. Is there an issue with using the following function to do so -

```
(defn lazy-coll [coll]
  (lazy-seq 
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (cons (first s) (lazy-coll (rest s))))))
```

This way I can use `map`, `remove` the way I normally would have.

Comment: FYI `defn` already has an implicit `do` block in the body.

Comment: In `compose-comparators`, you can replace `(filter #(not (zero? %))` with `(filter (complement zero?))` or `(remove zero?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected yourself and as the other answers have noted, the problem is that chunked sequences are not as lazy as they might be.

If we look at your `compose-comparators` function (slightly simplified)

```
(defn compose-comparators [& comparators]
  (fn [x y]
    (let [result (->> comparators
                      (map #(% x y))
                      (remove zero?)
                      first)]
      (if (nil? result) 0 result))))
```

... the reason that all three comparisons are run in `people-comparison-2` is that `map` deals with a chunked sequence in chunks, as you can see [here](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/map/).

A simple solution is to substitute a `map` with the chunkiness removed:

```
(defn lazy-map [f coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (cons (f (first s)) (lazy-map f (rest s))))))
```

---

By the way, you can abstract the construction of the comparator functions. If we define

```
(defn comparer [f]
  (fn [x y]
    (println "Comparing with " f)
    (compare (f x) (f y))))
```

... we can use it to define

```
(def people-comparision-2 
 (apply compose-comparators (map comparer [:fname :lname :mname])))
```

Comment: In the lazy-map example, should the function acting on `rest s` be `map` or `lazy-map`? Also, isn't it better to make the collection lazy as opposed to making just map lazy? I haven't looked, but am assuming other collection functions also behave differently when given a chunked sequence? Nice refactoring on the comparison functions.

Comment: @AmithGeorge 1. It should be `lazy-map` - corrected. 2. I don't think it matters whether we un-chunk `map` or the collection. I just thought the former was simpler. `filter` and `remove` preserve chunkedness too. 3. I got the impression that the  code in the book could often be better factored. Maybe its because Clojure constructs cost fewer tokens than Scala or C# ones that more factoring is evident.

Comment: I appended an edit to my question. As you suggested there isn't any difference between unchunking `map` or `collection`, I went with creating a lazy collection. I would like to hear any comments you have on the `lazy-coll` function. If not, then I shall mark this as the answer.

Comment: @AmithGeorge The `lazy-coll` function looks fine. In general, you should prefer using standard functions, as @noisesmith did, but in this case I don't like the ignored argument. Finally, until you asked this question, the implications of the chunkiness of `map`, `filter`, &c, hadn't really struck home.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests with your code and it happens that:

```
((compose-comparators fname-compare lname-compare mname-compare) person1 person2)
```

Does work as intended and compares `fname` only.

According to [this blog post](http://debasishg.blogspot.fr/2010/05/laziness-in-clojure-some-thoughts.html), laziness in Clojure might not be enforced as strictly as we might imagine:

> Clojure as a language is not lazy by default in totality (unlike
>   Haskell) and hence laziness may get mixed up with strict evaluation
>   leading to surprising and unoptimized consequences.

Comment: the second works correctly because it is eager. The author o f the question just found it not very "clojury".

Comment: @coredump, Interesting. What's the difference between what you posted and using an intermediate value? like so - `(def people-comparision-2 
  (compose-comparators fname-compare lname-compare mname-compare))
(people-comparision-2 person1 person2)` ... Why does the latter print execute all three functions, but the former only the first?

Comment: @AmithGeorge I don't know. I looked quickly at clojure's implementation but did not find anything relevant (I should spend more time). Somehow, the evaluation of the `fn` form behaves differently whether it is used right away or stored with `def`.

Comment: @coredump Wow, this is a new one for me.  It looks like the type selected for the variable-arity arg `comparators` is different when you assign the result to a var (i.e. use `def`) vs. just eval it https://gist.github.com/overthink/7669b95275ae2f11e496 (i.e. it'll be more preditctable if you don't use variable arity)

Comment: Rather than dig into the compiler I've asked about this :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/26042835/69689

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running into chunked sequences.  I'm not an expert on this, but my understanding is that depending on the type of sequence you have, clojure may evaluate it in chunks of 32 elements rather than being fully lazy.

e.g. Your first code (that didn't work as hoped) is effectively:

```
;; I renamed your compare fns to c1, c2, c3

(->> [c1 c2 c3] ; vector; will be chunked
     (map #(% person1 person2)) 
     (filter #(not (zero? %))) 
     first)

comparing fname
comparing lname
comparing mname
14
```

versus

```
(->> (list c1 c2 c3) ; list i.e. (cons c1 (cons c2 (cons c3 nil))) 
     (map #(% person1 person2)) 
     (filter #(not (zero? %))) 
     first)

;comparing fname
;14
```

Given this unfortunate behaviour you might want to try another approach.  How about this:

*(fixed version based on Amith George's comment below)*

```
(some (fn [f] 
        (let [result (f person1 person2)]
          (if (zero? result) false result)))
      [c1 c2 c3])

;comparing fname
;14
```

Comment: I had to rewrite the `some` example to - `(some #(let [result (% person1 person2)] (if (= result 0) false result)) [c1 c2 c3])
`. The former would print 0 if the first names are the same and not compare the last/middle names. Anyway, why does this work? I got the impression from your post that `vectors` are chunked and `lists` not. Then why does the `some` example which uses `vectors` work?

Comment: If you look at the source for some (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/03cd9d159a2c49a21d464102bb6d6061488b4ea2/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2560) you can see it's calling the fuctions one at a time.  Whether the values from the seq of functions given are realized one item at a time or 32 at a time doesn't matter since nothing happens till you call one of them. I think I'm demonstrating my lack of total understanding here :)

Comment: Seems I would need to re-read the Clojure basics. This is different from C#. Depending on the underlying collection implementation or the implementation of the function iterating over the collection, the output could differ. There still is the question as to why @coredump's answer behaves differently from my code. Your post answers my question. Though I would like to keep the question open for some more time. Maybe someone could explain why coredump's answer works.

Comment: The thing coredump noticed is really surprising.  I asked about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042835/how-does-clojure-determine-the-type-of-variable-arity-args

Answer (score 1):

We do, in fact, have something close to `yield`. It is called `reduced`.

It is only incidental that a `lazy-seq` avoids calculation of results, there is no strict guarantee that a result not used is not evaluated. This is beneficial for performance (it is often faster to calculate a chunk of results from a `lazy-seq` at once rather than one at a time).

What we want here is not laziness of results, but short circuiting if a specific result is found, and that is what `reduced` is designed for.

```
(defn compare-by-key
  [k]
  (fn [p1 p2]
    (println "Comparing" (name k))
    (compare (k p1) (k p2))))

(def fname-compare (compare-by-key :fname))

(def lname-compare (compare-by-key :lname))

(def mname-compare (compare-by-key :mname))

(defn make-composed-comparison [& comparisons] 
  (fn [p1 p2]
    (or (reduce (fn [_ comparison]
                  (let [compared (comparison p1 p2)]
                    (when-not (zero? compared)
                      (reduced compared))))
                false
                comparisons)
        0)))

(def people-comparison-1 
  (make-composed-comparison fname-compare lname-compare mname-compare))
```

I also attempted to make a few things more idiomatic here, hopefully your original code is still recognizable.

```
user> (people-comparison-1 person1 person2)
Comparing fname
14
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for introducing me to `reduced`. I am always looking for examples of idiomatic clojure code. Best way to learn :) Moving on, I find the `->>` example given by @overthink, the one which uses a list of comparison functions instead of a vector of functions to be more readable and clearer on intent. That's not to say your code is not readable or clear, it's most likely my greenness at clojure. Any reason, apart from personal preference, to pick one over the other?

Comment: I think that switching between list vs. vector to control chunking is a bit esoteric, and the more reliable approach is to explicitly short circuit when short circuiting is the behavior wanted. That said, his code is very clear. There is like a more clear version using reduce/reduced (likely with the help of `->>`).

Comment: Fair point. Coming from C#, it's `yield` gives me lazy sequence as well as early exit. I was expecting similar behaviour out of clojure's collections and functions. Chunked sequences however created a distinction. Given that `vector`, (ie clojure's goto collection, the way `List<T>` is C#'s goto collection) is chunked, it makes more sense to explicitly return early as opposed to converting a `vector` to a `list`. @Thumbnail suggested the solution of explicitly converting a vector to a non-chunked lazy sequence. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I marked @Thumbnail's post as the answer. I can see myself using `reduced` in the future. For this particular question though, using the `lazy-coll` function to explicitly get a lazy sequence seemed to make more sense to me.