# Why do Clojure variable arity args get different types depending on use?

Tags: types, clojure, variadic-functions

In answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039461/does-clojure-have-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-yield/26040454#comment40792827_26040416) I came across something I didn't expect with Clojure's variable arity function args:

```
user=> (defn wtf [& more] (println (type more)) :ok)
#'user/wtf

;; 1)
user=> (wtf 1 2 3 4)
clojure.lang.ArraySeq
:ok

;; 2)
user=> (let [x (wtf 1 2 3 4)] x)
clojure.lang.ArraySeq
:ok

;; 3)
user=> (def x (wtf 1 2 3 4))
clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq
#'user/x
user=> x
:ok
```

Why is the type `ArraySeq` in 1) and 2), but `PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq` in 3)?

Comment: It gets better: `((fn[] (def x (wtf 1 2 3 4))))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer:** It's an obscure implementation detail of Clojure. The only thing guaranteed by the language is that the rest-param of a variadic function will be passed as an instance of `clojure.lang.ISeq`, or `nil` if there are no additional arguments. You should code accordingly.

**Long answer:** It has to do with whether the function call is compiled or simply evaluated. Without going into a full dissertation on the difference between evaluation and compilation, it should be sufficient to know that Clojure code gets parsed into an AST. Depending on the context, expressions in the AST could get evaluated directly (something akin to interpretation), or could get compiled into Java bytecode as part of a dynamically-generated class. The typical case where the latter happens is in the body of a lambda expression, which will evaluate to an instance of a dynamically generated class that implements the `IFn` interface. See the [Clojure documentation](http://clojure.org/evaluation) for a more detailed explanation of evaluation.

The vast majority of the time, the difference between compiled and evaluated code will be invisible to your program; they will behave in exactly the same way. This is one of those rare corner cases where compilation and evaluation result in subtly different behavior. It's important to point out, though, that both behaviors are correct in that they conform to the promises made by the language.

Function calls in Clojure code get parsed into an instance of `InvokeExpr` in `clojure.lang.Compiler`. If the code is being compiled, then the compiler emits bytecode that will call the `invoke` method on an `IFn` object using an appropriate arity ([Compiler.java, line 3650](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L3650)). If the code is just being evaluated and not compiled, then the function arguments are bundled up in a `PersistentVector` and passed to the `applyTo` method on the `IFn` object ([Compiler.java, line 3553](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L3553)).

Clojure functions that have a variadic arg list are compiled into subclasses of the [`clojure.lang.RestFn`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RestFn.java) class. This class implements all the methods of `IFn`, gathers arguments, and dispatches to the appropriate `doInvoke` arity. You can see in the implementation of `applyTo` that, in the case of 0 required args (as is the case in your `wtf` function), the input seq is passed through to the `doInvoke` method and visible to the function implementation. The 4-arg version of `invoke`, meanwhile, bundles up the arguments in an `ArraySeq` and passes this to the `doInvoke` method, so now your code sees an `ArraySeq`.

To complicate matters, the implementation of Clojure's `eval` function (which is what the REPL is calling) will internally wrap a list form being evaluated inside a thunk (an anoymous, no-arg function), then compile and execute the thunk. So almost all invocations are using compiled calls to the `invoke` method, rather than being interpreted directly by the compiler. There's a special case for `def` forms that explicitly evaluates the code without compiling, which accounts for the different behavior you're seeing there.

The implementation of `clojure.core/apply` also calls the `applyTo` method, and by this logic whatever list type passed to `apply` should be seen the the function body. Indeed:

```
user=> (apply wtf [1 2 3 4])
clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq
:ok

user=> (apply wtf (list 1 2 3 4))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
:ok
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you clarify what you mean by "explicitly evaluates the code without compiling"? What does it mean to evaluate code that is not compiled?

Comment: Clojure code gets parsed into an AST. Depending on the context, expressions in the AST could get evaluated directly (something akin to interpretation), or could get compiled into Java bytecode as part of a dynamically-generated class. The typical case where this happens is in the body of a lambda expression, which will evaluate to an instance of a dynamically generated class that implements the `IFn` interface.

Comment: I know this is veering off topic but... The things not compiled to bytecode: are you talking about stuff like symbol resolution and forms that evaluate to themselves like keywords, strings, numbers, etc?

Comment: Yes, it turns out that since evaluation wraps most list forms inside an anonymous `fn`, those cases you mention, along with the special case of `def` forms, are the only instances where evaluation avoids bytecode generation.

Comment: I would appreciate, if you could provide a summary. I have read the answer multiple times and I am not sure of the following. 1. If the forms mentioned in the question were put in a file, compiled to a jar, executed via java, what would the type be?. 2. When we "evaluate" a form via the IDE and when we type a form into the REPL,in both cases are we not simply evaluating? According to answer, it looks like the action uses `eval` which results in compilation, except in case of `def`.  3. Does this imply that the output seen in REPL can be different from the output from actual program execution?

Comment: @AmithGeorge If you're referring to AOT-compiled code, then yes, you can get different results when executing code in the REPL vs executed from the command line. For you other questions, I hope my edits have cleared things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure is for the most part not implemented in terms of Classes, but in terms of Interfaces and Protocols (a Clojure abstraction over java Interfaces with a few extra features).

```
user> (require '[clojure.reflect :as reflect])
nil
user> (:bases (reflect/reflect clojure.lang.ArraySeq))
#{clojure.lang.IndexedSeq clojure.lang.IReduce clojure.lang.ASeq}
user> (:bases (reflect/reflect clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq))
#{clojure.lang.Counted clojure.lang.IChunkedSeq clojure.lang.ASeq}
```

good Clojure code doesn't work in terms of `ArraySeq` vs. `PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq`, but rather will call the methods or protocol functions exposed by `IndexedSeq`, `IReduce`, `ASeq`, etc. if their argument implements them. Or more likely, use the basic `clojure.core` functions that are implemented in terms of these interfaces or protocols.

For example, note the definition of `reduce`:

```
user> (source reduce)
(defn reduce
  "f should be a function of 2 arguments. If val is not supplied,
  returns the result of applying f to the first 2 items in coll, then
  applying f to that result and the 3rd item, etc. If coll contains no
  items, f must accept no arguments as well, and reduce returns the
  result of calling f with no arguments.  If coll has only 1 item, it
  is returned and f is not called.  If val is supplied, returns the
  result of applying f to val and the first item in coll, then
  applying f to that result and the 2nd item, etc. If coll contains no
  items, returns val and f is not called."
  {:added "1.0"}
  ([f coll]
     (clojure.core.protocols/coll-reduce coll f))
  ([f val coll]
     (clojure.core.protocols/coll-reduce coll f val)))
nil
```

and if you look up `coll-reduce`, you find various implementations based on the Interfaces or Protocols implemented: [protocols.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core/protocols.clj)

```
(extend-protocol CollReduce
  nil
  (coll-reduce
   ([coll f] (f))
   ([coll f val] val))

  Object
  (coll-reduce
   ([coll f] (seq-reduce coll f))
   ([coll f val] (seq-reduce coll f val)))

  clojure.lang.IReduce
  (coll-reduce
   ([coll f] (.reduce coll f))
   ([coll f val] (.reduce coll f val)))

  ;;aseqs are iterable, masking internal-reducers
  clojure.lang.ASeq
  (coll-reduce
   ([coll f] (seq-reduce coll f))
   ([coll f val] (seq-reduce coll f val)))
  ...) ; etcetera
```

Comment: I agree with what's said here, but it doesn't address the question.

Comment: I may not be explicit enough about connecting it back to the question, but this is my attempt at the "why" (whereas @Alex addresses "how").

Comment: My question could probably be more pointed.  I appreciate your taking time to answer nonetheless.